ROS2 Humble Launch - How to Get Log Level to Output Launch File Error Traceback
Looking for any pointers on changing log level of LAUNCH directly, not individuals nodes, to view tracebacks of launch file errors.
Specifically:

My launch file command is ros2 launch diff_drive_robot_example diff_drive_robot_example_ros2_control.launch.py

The response is:
 [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): expected string or bytes-like object, got 'LaunchConfiguration'

I want to see the "debug for traceback" to see where in the launch file, or nested launch file, the error is occurring. The following --ros-args do not change the above output:
ros2 launch diff_drive_robot_example diff_drive_robot_example_ros2_control.launch.py --ros-args --log-level debug

I have also tried editing the main launch file itself including the following with no change:
SetLaunchConfiguration('log_level', 'debug')
SetEnvironmentVariable('RCUTILS_LOGGING_SEVERITY_THRESHOLD', 'DEBUG')

I have also looked in the log files as diected by the script and have seen no additional information beyond what is being printed in the terminal.


Setup:

ROS2 Humble via Robostack & Conda


You can use the launch command arguments -d and -a, ex ros2 launch <package> <file> -d -a, which should display all debug related output present in the various nodes.

Thanks Ethan, this worked great.
